# Grey out CheckBox in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, checkbox

How to **grey out** a checkbox? 
I want a checkbox to be clickable only if another checkbox is enabled.

Comment: Don't give -1 without any reason, at least explain why!

Comment: I guess you have been given -1 since you don't submit any code, you have just asked for help without any trace of research effort.

Comment: Answer to that question is very easy because iF you search on Google or on stackoverflow you find!

Comment: perhaps they felt you hadn't shown any research effort. your question doesn't indicate what you had tried so far to solve this issue.

Comment: I checked on SO before asking question, and there are not similar questions. And the source code is not required for submitting an answer! (It's well accepted but not required!)

Comment: Downvote button: "The question does not show any research effort" -- Your question: does not SHOW any research effort. It's the _research effort_ that's required, not source code.

Comment: Could you explain why people continue voting down the question? I think they like doing it...

Comment: I think it's because you commented about the downvotes. I don't know why that provokes others to downvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `setEnabled(boolean)`